# Java Runtime Exception

Tags: java, swing, exception

when i run my application i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView$FlowStrategy.layoutRow(FlowView.java:546)
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView$FlowStrategy.layout(FlowView.java:460)
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView.layout(FlowView.java:184)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(BoxView.java:380)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.updateChildSizes(BoxView.java:349)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(BoxView.java:331)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(BoxView.java:691)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(BoxView.java:380)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(BasicTextUI.java:1702)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.modelToView(BasicTextUI.java:1034)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.repaintNewCaret(DefaultCaret.java:1291)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$1.run(DefaultCaret.java:1270)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

as the error does not mention any of my classes, how would i go about in finding what is causing this?

if i try: `public void notifyChatMessage(String message){...}` the error goes away (NOT).

*edit: upon further testing it turns out the above generates the error also.*

but if i try: `public void notifyChatMessage(Object message){...}` the error is reported.

please advise.

EDIT:

```
        public void notifyChatMessage(String message){


         AppMessage appMessage = new AppMessage(AppMessage.Target.Chat, message);
         setChanged();
         notifyObservers(appMessage);

     }
```

AppMessage:

```
public class AppMessage implements Serializable {

/**
 * Message header for target: game, chat
 */
public enum Target {
    Game, Chat
}

/**
 * Holds target
 */
public Target target;

/**
 * Holds state message
 */
public Object message;

/**
 * Construct using parameter data
 * @param target
 * @param message
 */
public AppMessage(Target target, Object message){

    this.target = target;
    this.message = message;

}

}
```

EDIT: even with the error report the program continues to run and i cannot see any lack of performance ie. error in running which is making the task of localizing the problem more complex.

**EDIT: when i run it through the debugger in netbeans i get: *Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.***

**EDIT: the exception is being thrown because of cross thread GUI updates. investigating invokeLater and invokeAndWait for solution.**

**SOLUTION:** [invokeAndWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850865/java-invokelater-of-c-action-delegate)

Comment: Could you post more of the code around where the error is occurring?

Comment: You're passing a null argument which is fine with one method but erroneous with another. Post more code.

Comment: thats what i said.. the error does not localise itself.. i dont know.

Comment: You've managed to identify the `notifyChatMessage()` method; from where do you call it?  What do you do inside it?

Comment: @Yuval A: likely but exactly where?! how do i locate it if it does not mention a location in my code. good tip though. i will have to revise the entire code slowly.

Comment: I can't tell where your posted code interfaces with Swing, but that's where I'd focus my search.

Comment: All you posted is irrelevant code. Try to focus on where the problem is exactly and give us more to work with.

Comment: please see my next post. i think that is the issue thats reporting this exception.

Comment: yes my next post has solved the nonspecific exception issue.

Answer (score 1):

The call `javax.swing.text.FlowView$FlowStrategy.layoutRow(FlowView.java:546)` is trying to process something that is `NULL`. Looking at its signature. [layoutRow(FlowView fv, int rowIndex, int pos)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/FlowView.FlowStrategy.html#layoutRow%28javax.swing.text.FlowView,%20int,%20int%29)  the only thing that can be `NULL` is `FlowView fv` since the `int` primatives can't be `NULL`. So without having the code to run and step debug thru, I would say that somewhere something is either not setting FlowView or setting it to `NULL`.

Comment: Actually, it's viewBuffer which is null, a field of the FlowView class.

Answer (score -1):

Use the source... start with `javax.swing.text.FlowView` line 546

Comment: i tried that but thats Java lib code and i dont know that it is saying exactly.

Comment: Convenience link: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/swing/text/FlowView.java.html

Comment: @Lord Torgamus nice one but probably the wrong version as the last line in that source file is 412. The correct java file will be in `src.zip`

Comment: you may be right.  I almost didn't post the link for that very reason, but I thought it was due to docjar automation snipping out the static classes, changing the line numbers but not the code.  Either way though, using `src.zip` will be ironclad.